# Unexpected result in ByteBuffer.js when writing a variable integer

Tags: javascript, bytebuffer

Below, I'm trying to write out 0x16 as a variable integer.  I'm expecting to see 0x2C, but instead I get 0x16.  Any idea how I may adjust my use of ByteBuffer to get the expected result?  Please follow the comments below:

http://jsfiddle.net/jslim180/h1ojuc54/

```
ByteBuffer = window.dcodeIO.ByteBuffer

b = new ByteBuffer(DEFAULT_CAPACITY=4, ByteBuffer.LITTLE_ENDIAN)

console.log '22 decimal is 0x16 hex: ' + (22).toString(16)

# 22 can be represented in less than 7 bits so the least significant bit 
# should be 0 (indicating that no additional bytes are needed)
b.writeVarint32 22 
b.printDebug() # Not expected: prints 0x16 .. this did not bitshift at all

# If I bit-shift manually, I get the expected result: 0x2C
console.log (0x16<<1).toString(16) # prints 2c
```

https://github.com/dcodeIO/ByteBuffer.js/wiki/API

(btw: this is coffeescript, javascript without the parentheses)

Answer (score 0):

ByteBuffer is writing out unsigned varint.  I need to use writeVaruint32.  https://github.com/dcodeIO/ByteBuffer.js/issues/44